# When i should change the Default isolation level used by EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i am using EF to map my current database tables. now whenever i issue an update statement using EF the sql profiler will mention the following:-

> set transaction isolation level read committed.

Which means that EF will do the following :-

1. Lock any records from being updated/read if it was modified by a transaction but not yet committed. Will prevent dirty reads.
2. Any read operation will return a committed data, and no intermediate data will be read.

So i find that this isolation level is sufficient in most cases, so when do i need to changed the EF default isolation level?